# I am trying to free the memory occupied by an element in the structure using free(), but its not working

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, free

I have this struct Exam. and i am using cleanUp function to allocate and free the memory occupied by title but its not freeing it.

```
    typedef struct
    {
        char* title;
        Question* questions[MAX_QUESTIONS];
    }Exam;

    BOOL CleanUp(Exam * e){
    char name[200];
        printf("Enter name of the course \n");
        gets(name);
        fflush(stdout);
        e->title = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(name)+1));
        strcpy(e->title,name);

        free(e->title);
    }
```

Comment: how do you see, that it is not free'ing it?

Comment: Why would you want to free it? if you haven't used it yet?

Comment: NEVER EVER use gets(); never!

Comment: and it is good advise not to cast the result of malloc()

Comment: And you probably want to flush *before* you call fgets. (after you replace gets with fgets, that is)

Comment: You have a mistake in your `malloc`, you misused the `sizeof()` operator and the ugly and bad style cast, but other than that, nothing is wrong, so `free()` should work as you expect.

Comment: Replace `gets` with `fgets`, `gets` IS DEPRECATED!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(strlen(name)+1)` is not correct, this gives you the size of the result of that calculation, i.e. `sizeof(int)`.  Because you have allocated the wrong size you are writing past the end of the buffer.

**This is corrupting data and causing `free()` to fail.**

What you mean to do is:

```
sizeof(char) * (strlen(name) + 1)
```

In C, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, so you don't actually need it here, however I've put it there to illustrate the general way to allocate memory for multiple objects: multiply the size of the object by the number of objects.

Comment: Edited to say why allocating the wrong size will cause free() to fail

Comment: e->title = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) *(strlen(name)+1));
using this will work?

Comment: `e->title = malloc(strlen(name)+1); ` this will be enough, and please check that `malloc` didn't return `NULL` before calling `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you simply meant:

```
e->title = strdup(name);

...

free(e->title);
```

strdup() will count the string pointed to by 'name', allocate space for a copy (including the null terminator) and copy the data in a sensible, architecture aligned way (usually.)`

Answer (score 0):

I think Whilom Chime gave a pretty adequete answer, as did Mr. Zebra. Another way to do it would be like so;

`e->title = malloc(sizeof(char *));`

`if(e->title != NULL)    strcpy(e->title, word);`

However, I've found when working with really large data sets (I had to put ~3M words into a 2-3-4 tree a couple days ago), `e->title = strdup(word);` is actually faster than `strcpy(e->title, word);`. I don't know why, and it honestly doesn't make sense to me, seeing as strcpy doesn't have to go through the process of allocating memory for the character pointer. Maybe someone else can give input on this